# Rigidbody keeps in air, after ground moved (sometimes)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an prefab (green diamond) which has a rigidbody and ground which the player can control.

In some situations the prefab seems not to reconize that the ground was moved. The prefab falls on the ground once hit by something or if the ground moved further away(sometimes).

As the player only triggers to move the ground, does I somehow have to inform the prefab that is has to refresh its physics?

Tried every "Interpolation" and "Collision Detection" combination.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Rigidbody.WakeUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.WakeUp.html). It might be what you're looking for, although I don't know if there's a better way to address this problem.

Comment: At least it solved my problem. So far I dont have any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct handling. For my specific case. Is to use rigidbody instead of direct(transformation) manipulation of the ground.

After using "this.rigidbody.rotation = ... " in a fixedUpdate methode I couldn't reproduce this issue either.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

> FixedUpdate should be used instead of Update when dealing with Rigidbody. For example when adding a force to a rigidbody, you have to apply the force every fixed frame inside FixedUpdate instead of every frame inside Update.